# How to use multiple conjunctions in a sentence?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

Basically…

I'm trying to figure out the best sentence format to execute code for high school students.

1 sentence can execute multiple code.

The sentence format will be based on an `IF Statment`.

`If this is true` - `trigger event` - `find element(s)` - `change these properties`-to-`this`

## Example

Sentence Input 1

> If Susan's house is yellow, change the doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.

Sentence Input 2

> If Susan's house is yellow, change Paul's doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.

Sentence Input 3

> If Susan's house is yellow, change Brandon's and Paul's doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.

Sentence Input 4

> If Susan's house is yellow, change Brandon's, Tiffany's, and Paul's doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.

**What I'm thinking**

> If Susan's house is yellow, change the doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.
>
> If Susan's house is yellow, change Paul's doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.
>
> If Susan's house is yellow, change (Brandon's and Paul's) doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.
>
> If Susan's house is yellow, change (Brandon's, Tiffany's, and Paul's) doors, windows, and porch color to blue, green, or purple.

Comment: *If Susan's house is yellow, change the color of doors, windows and porch of Brandon, Tiffany and Paul to blue, green or purple*. OR, *If Susan's house is yellow, change Brandon's, Tiffany's and Paul's doors, windows and porch color to blue, green or purple*.

Comment: If this was easily doable, then the job of business analyst (in a programming context) would cease to be. There is an entire profession dedicated to explaining things in a way that make sense to both (code-minded) developers and (common word usage) users. If English is written in a way that is logically sound, it entails a lot of repetitive word usage and detailed distinctions, which make it very hard to parse and understand.

Comment: The best example of this is a well known joke. _A programmer is going to the grocery store and his wife tells him, "Buy a gallon of milk, and if there are eggs, buy a dozen." So the programmer goes, buys everything, and drives back to his house. Upon arrival, his wife angrily asks him, "Why did you get 13 gallons of milk?" The programmer says, "There were eggs!"__

Comment: Your example formatting is readable, **because we understand what you mean**. But the text you are writing should also be understood by **people who don't already know what you mean** (since it's intended to **explain** something to those people), and for those people, your formatting may not be self-evident. You'd need to first teach these people how to read your formatting, which means you're going out of scope of **the English language** and are instead using a custom style system.

Comment: @AllenMarshall: You're missing the point. The programmer and his wife understood the same sentence in two completely different ways, because **common speech is not explicitly logical**. Another example: explain to me the difference between "doors, windows, **and** porch" and "blue, green, **or** purple". Why are you using "and"/"or"? How are these different? Does "or" mean that **any** of the listed colors is fine, or are you expecting e.g. a specific color based on the owner or the object that is being colored?

Comment: Hey, Allen; you'd be a lot closer to solving your problem if you'd understood what Flater said.

I'm so very sorry for all your students to say this, and if you think *If this is true - trigger event - find element(s) - change these properties-to-this* is unambiguous or even complete in Javascript or English or any other language, then all you had to do was look at this way in the first place: *English follows a precise set of rules. They can readily be translated into Javascript. There's nothing left to Question. Let's not bother the helpful guys at ELL SE.*